# Add animation to bootstrap Tooltip with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use css animation framework "animate.css" to add animation to bootstrap tooltip.
I have 3 buttoms:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="animated X" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="645" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button" data-original-title="Select options">Select options</a>

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="animated Y" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="645" class="add_to_wishlist" data-original-title="Add to Wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a>

<div class="quickview" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="animated Z" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="" data-id="645" data-original-title="Quick View">Quick View</div>
```

I want that jquery find the "data-animation" and add it as a class,
for example:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="animated X" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="645" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button animated X" data-original-title="Select options">Select options</a>
```

I tried to do it with this code but nothing was happened:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
        $('.tooltip').addClass('animated ' + $('.tooltip').data('animation'));
    })
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zc0qjsv/9/)

Comment: Please share a JSFiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8zc0qjsv/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Following [this pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13711), [this demo](http://output.jsbin.com/vefici/6) and [this post](https://medium.com/@_tushar_/custom-animations-in-bootstrap3-c20c0973ceb2),
here is a simplified solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/eqtd2o3d/

This way you just need to use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```

Comment: No.. It mess up all the tooltips.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: The jquery seems to work fine, But can you tell me why the tooltips goes to different places?

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! (:

Answer (score 0):

Why not the built-in bootstrap setting:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({animation:true});
});
```